# Determining rectagle width and height, when given perimeter and space

Tags: geometry

What would be the formula, to determine a rectagles edges, when given the perimeter and space? for example, the rectagles space is 80, and the perimeter is 36, and the edge would be 8 and 10, but how do I find them.

I know that the formula for the perimeter would be
2x+2y=per, or 2(space/y)+2y=per
However I'm trying to figure out how to find x and y, when I only know space and perimeter.

Comment: Are you by chance not a native English speaker? I think you mean rectangle *area*, not space.

Comment: Yes, my apologies, english is my second language. And yes, I do mean area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By space, do you mean area?

So we know that $$2x + 2y = P$$ and also that $$xy = A.$$ This means that, as you pointed out, $$2\frac{A}{y} + 2y = P$$ and thus that $$A + y^2 - \frac{P}{2}y = 0$$ which we get by multiplying both sides by $y$. You can use the quadratic formula to solve for $y$ now, where you get that $$y = \frac{P/2 \pm \sqrt{P^2/4 - 4A}}{2}.$$ Use your knowledge of algebra to simplify this expression for $y$ and then solve for $x$ and you're home!

Answer (score 1):

I am going to use $A$ for area and $p$ for perimeter to enhance readability.

$a, b > 0$ so you can divide, take roots, etc. - whatever you want. Your goal is to solve the system of equations:
$$A = a*b$$
$$p = 2a+2b$$

So you do the following:
$$A = a*b \implies \frac{A}{a}=b$$
$$\implies p = 2a+\frac{A}{a}$$
$$\implies \frac{a \cdot p}{2}=a^2+A$$
$$\implies 0=a^2-\frac{p}{2}a+A$$
Solving the quadratic equation gives:
$$a=\frac{p}{4} \pm \sqrt{\frac{p^2}{16}-A}$$
Put your two results for a into the original equation and solve it for b and you get the following pairs of solutions:
$$\left(\frac{p}{4} + \sqrt{\frac{p^2}{16}-A},\frac{p}{4} - \sqrt{\frac{p^2}{16}-A}\right),\left(\frac{p}{4} - \sqrt{\frac{p^2}{16}-A},\frac{p}{4} + \sqrt{\frac{p^2}{16}-A}\right)$$

(due to the fact that $a$ and $b$ are interchangeable).

You'll like the solutions, by the way.

By the way, this is not really gometry - it's a little piece of algebra.

(If you like, you can turn this into an Analysis question now: what's the maximum area for given perimeter?)

Answer (score 0):

length = $l$, breadth = $b$

space, $lb = 80$

perimeter, $2(l+b) = 36$

$$l + \frac{80}{l} - 18 = 0$$
$$l^2-18.l+80=0$$
$$(l-10)(l-8)$$
So, $l=10$ or $l=8$.

But since length > breadth:
$$length=10$$
$$breadth=8$$